# Removing tree stems from a point cloud in R

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

I am studying the foliage density of forest plots below 2 metres in height using mobile terrestrial laser scanning. I want to filter out the tree stems from the point clouds so that the point density estimates do not include them. I have been using the lidR and TreeLS packages to process my point clouds. So far I have normalized the clouds and classified the tree stems using example code given in the TreeLS package documentation:

```
tls1 = readTLS("tls1.las") %>%
tlsNormalize %>%
tlsSample
map = treeMap(tls1, map.hough())
tls2 = treePoints(tls1, map, trp.crop(circle=FALSE))
tls3 = stemPoints(tls2, stm.hough(pixel_size = 0.03))
```

This successfully identifies the tree stems.

To filter the stems out, I have tried using the filter_poi() function:

```
tls4 <- filter_poi(tls3, Stem = "FALSE")
```

There is a column in the point cloud dataset entitled "Stem" with TRUE/FALSE values so I thought this would work, but I get this error:

```
Error in lasfilter_(las, lazyeval::dots_capture(...)) : 
  `conditions` must be logical.
```

Comment: It is just incorrect R syntax. Use `filter_poi(tls3, Stem == FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks JRR that works without an error. However, when I then plot the scan before and after filtering the stem points, there is no change in the image. When I look for unique values in the Stem column "TRUE" has been removed, so the filtering has worked. There must be a problem with the stem classification?

Comment: Are you sure the stems were properly segmented initially in `tls3`? If not it is no longer a `lidR` question. Can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try classifying the stems in the 'Classification' column after calling `stemPoints`.

I've used the following code to classify and then filter stems:

> **Classify**
>
> ```
> tls@data[Stem == T, Classification := 20]
> ```
>
> **then filter**
>
> ```
> stems  = filter_poi(tls, Classification == 20L)
> ```